# Как при наведении на родительский блок изменить цвет границы дочернего блока?

Tags: javascript, css

Как при наведении на родительский блок `parent` изменить `borderColor` у дочернего блока `children`? Блок `children` является дочерним классом `parent`.

[image]

Comment: а разметку можно увидеть?

Comment: <div class="parent"><div class="children">block</div>text</div>

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
  background-color: chocolate;
  padding: 20px;
}

.children {
  background-color: gold;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: white;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.parent:hover .children {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">block</div>
  text
</div>
```

Comment: это конечно не то) но все равно спасибо) я имел в виду createStyles, а не css)